# function inside immutable js and redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am developing an app using react, redux + immutable js.

All of my app state is in a redux store that only has immutable members. I wonder if it is allowed to have functions stored inside them. The use case I have is that I have descriptions of form elements in my state and I render them using react. Some form elements require validation so the easiest way is to just store the function inside the state. This works but I have a feeling this is some kind of bad practice. I can't seem to find anything online.

Any help is appreciated!

something like this:

```
Map({
  a: stuff
  b: List.of(
    ...
    // some UI form element that requires a function to validate
    Map({
      // other informations....   
      validate: value => 'success',
      ...
    })
    ...
  ),
  c: moreStuff
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's generally discouraged, as it breaks abilities like time travel debugging.  The [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-non-serializable) covers this topic: